# FAQ in Drupal, using vocabularies?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

### Hi Drupal enthusiasts!

I am trying to design way of organizing FAQ on Drupal page.

Does anyone know about module that implements following use case?

2 vocabularies: faq categories, faq items grouping.

### Example:

Faq Categories:

- Application
- - Calculator
- - Paint
- - Notepad

Faq Grouping:

- Using cursor
- Printing
- Saving

Now I create question, I may choose Paint and Notepad tags for categories, to show a question in both categories. Then I choose printing term to show this question next to other one, which is also printing group.

Do you think I should struggle with Views? I don't think it's gonna fulfil following use case. Probably I need to write code by myself.. Question can be assigned to as many grouping and category terms as wanted, as some questions are referring to multiple..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out you can do this with Views. You list all content with some category tags, then you sort them with grouping tag and remove not needed headers (duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Faq](http://drupal.org/project/faq) module? You might be able to achieve what you trying to do. If am not mistaken it uses views :)

Comment: Yes, I looked up for a module before and I saw that. As far as I remember (also telling by screenshots on their page), it doesn't do question grouping as I need. Thanks anyway ;)